# "Terminated due to timeout error"¿Como puedo optimizar mi código?

Tags: java, bucles

```
static int minimumSwaps(int[] arr) {    
    int cont,v2[];
    v2=arr.clone();

    Arrays.sort(v2);
    return cont= Contar(arr,v2);               
}

static int Contar(int[] v1, int[] v2) {       
    //v1 desordenado.
    int aux;
    int cc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < v2.length; j++) {

            if (v1[i] == v2[j] && i == j) {
                break;
            }
            if (v1[i] == v2[j] && i!=j) {
                aux = v1[j];
                v1[j] = v2[j];
                v1[i] = aux;
                i--;
                cc++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cc;
}
```

Hola! este es un código que cuenta los mínimos cambios que hay que hacer a un array desordenado para poder ordenarlo. Es un reto de HackerRank(pagina de ejercicios) el tema es que en 4 casos de testeo me da el error "Terminated due to timeout error" que aparentemente es porque no da bien el tiempo de ejecución, la solución seria optimizar el código pero no se me ocurre o no pude. Desde ya gracias por las sugerencias!!! 
SALIDA ESPERADA: para 4 3 1 2 seria 3 (3 cambios minimos para ordear el array).

Comment: ¿Cuál es la entrada y salida esperada?

Comment: 4-
4 3 1 2 -es uno de los casos por ejemplo. 4 es el numero de extension del array y el resto es el relleno. El código funciona, pero cuando se hace el testo con cifras muy altas (arriba de mil en extensión de array por ejemplo) me tira el error mencionado.